# Change style onhover and log element info onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

A button that is a function and possess two things:

1.1: When I hover over any element(div, p, a, body) in page, the background(css) of that element needs to be changed(red for example) just to know that I hovered over the element that I wanted. And when onmouseleaves that element, the css is restored.

[Example when its hovered over footers div. (picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bglir.png)

1.2: When I click on the element, I want console.log that element(object). The trick is that when I click over that element and if element is for example image or link, their effect needs to be disabled, such that I just get the console.log and not the effects that that element possess (expand the image, redirect the page...).

1.3: Function ends

These are the features that one AdBlocker possess and I want to know how they work in the background in a javascript manner.

[The feature that Im talking about. (picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOzi3.png)

Comment: Where's the code that you have tried?

Comment: For point 1.1 you can use CSS instead